# Automatically fix / remove invalid row from Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a DataGrid with a validation rule inside *RowValidationRules* markup.

What I want is to have the binded property updated ONLY if there are no validation errors, otherwise should keep the old values.

xaml:

```
<DataGrid                          
Margin="10" 
CanUserAddRows="True" 
CanUserDeleteRows="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
IsReadOnly="False"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static services:SharedPropertiesProvider.Instance}, Path=Aliases, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"                        
>

<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <validation:AliasValidation />
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="30*" Header="Alias" Binding="{Binding Key, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="70*" Header="Path" Binding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" Width="20" Height="20">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Margin="2" Source="/WinLogInspector;component/Assets/1441392968_f-cross_256.png" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

validation class:

```
class AliasValidation : ValidationRule {
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
    if (((BindingGroup)value).Items.Count > 0)
    {
        Alias item = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as Alias;

        if (item != null)
        {
            string aliasPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

            string pathPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\/@:_\-;]+$";

            string key = item.Key ?? String.Empty;

            string path = item.Value ?? String.Empty;

            bool isValidAlias = Regex.IsMatch(key, aliasPattern);

            bool isValidPath = Regex.IsMatch(path, pathPattern);

            if (isValidAlias && isValidPath)
                return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            else
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Invalid alias / path");
        }
    }            

    return ValidationResult.ValidResult;

} }
```

The property in viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }

class Alias
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

So if I try to execute any command from the viewmodel I can see the the *Aliases* property has the invalid rows.
How I can sanitize this ?

Comment: I'd recommend using IDataErrorInfo in your Alias ViewModel/Model. From my use, it doesn't update the binding if it fails validation. But I'm surprised this method does. Wait, are you performing the validation on the actual ItemsControl?

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is I put the validation on the Datagrid instead of the binding ?

Comment: I suspect so, put my thoughts into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was completely wrong. Failed validation does update the binding! The only workaround I can think of at the moment is to have new display properties, and also validate in the setter...

```
    public string key;
    public string Key {
        get { return key; }
        set
        {
            if (key != value && this["KeyDisplay"] == string.Empty)
            {
                key = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Key");
            }
        }
    }

    public string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value && this["ValueDisplay"] == string.Empty)
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public string keyDisplay;
    public string KeyDisplay
    {
        get { return keyDisplay; }
        set
        {
            if (keyDisplay != value)
            {
                keyDisplay = value;
                Key = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("KeyDisplay");
            }
        }
    }

    public string valueDisplay;
    public string ValueDisplay
    {
        get { return valueDisplay; }
        set
        {
            if (valueDisplay != value)
            {
                valueDisplay = value;
                Value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ValueDisplay");
            }
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == nameof(KeyDisplay) || columnName == nameof(ValueDisplay))
            {
                string aliasPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

                string pathPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\/@:_\-;]+$";

                string key = KeyDisplay ?? String.Empty;

                string path = ValueDisplay ?? String.Empty;

                bool isValidAlias = Regex.IsMatch(key, aliasPattern);

                bool isValidPath = Regex.IsMatch(path, pathPattern);

                if (isValidAlias && isValidPath)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return "Invalid alias / path";
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

---

**This is the original answer and completely incorrect!** Validation prevents updating of the property associated with the binding. I'd guess you're properties are getting set even though they don't pass validation is because those properties aren't actually being validated. You're enabeling `NotifyOnValidationError=True` validation only on the ItemsControl ItemsSource property.

With MVVM I'd really recommend using IDataErrorInfo and validating in the ViewModel or Model - Validation isn't display related, and doesn't belong in the view in my opinion.

```
class Alias : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == nameof(Key) || columnName == nameof(Value))
            {
                string aliasPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";

                string pathPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\/@:_\-;]+$";

                string key = Key ?? String.Empty;

                string path = Value ?? String.Empty;

                bool isValidAlias = Regex.IsMatch(key, aliasPattern);

                bool isValidPath = Regex.IsMatch(path, pathPattern);

                if (isValidAlias && isValidPath)
                    return string.Empty;
                else
                    return "Invalid alias / path";
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

It also gives you more flexibility to check multiple properties are valid, as you have access to the whole data model in the binding logic. I think with ValidationRules you might have to mess around with multi-binding or something.

If you do stick with ValidationRules if you used validation in your Key and Value bindings: `Binding="{Binding Key, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True...}">` they shouldn't get updated on failure.

Comment: I've updated the code (It was necessary to add ValidatesOnDataErrors=True also) but the bad data is still taken :(

Comment: Just tested it, you're right. It shows on the UX, but still updates the property. What a pain. I always thought it rejected the binding! I'd guess the only way to manage it would be to have a display property, and a data property - and only update the data property when valid.

Comment: Added a workaround to the answer. Not ideal (I hate having to add more properties if at all possible), but works provided you always remember to bind to the display Property. Can't help but think there's a better solution though...

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort :-)